# Exported animation loops automatically

Tags: export, animation

I want to export an animation,

```
anim = Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationDirection -> Forward]
```

then export it

```
Export["animation.gif", anim]
```

the outputs loops. $a$ runs from $0 \to 5$ and then from $5 \to 0$ when I explicitly instructed that it should only repeat once and only go forward. I've tried other output file formats and all of them looped.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `Bookmarks`:

```
   anim = Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}, 
          Bookmarks -> {"start" :> {a = 0}, "stop" :> {a = 5}}];
   Export["animation.gif", anim]
```

Comment: I tried to increase the animations length with `DefaultDuration -> 10`. The output from Mathematica respects the command but the exported _ogv_ is always around 3 secs, with or without the Bookmark. Here [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MultimediaFormats.html] it suggests the use of "Duration" in the Export symbol but I tried adding it as a parameter in Export but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ vozdrugíja Try `Export["animation.ogv", anim,"AnimationDuration" -> 15]`, 15 being 15 secs.